# Can't understand specific kind of kotlin functions

Tags: kotlin

For example:

```
private fun TextView.onEndDrawableClicked(onClicked: (view: TextView) -> Unit) {
    this.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        var hasConsumed = false
        if (v is TextView) {
            if (event.x >= v.width - v.totalPaddingRight) {
                if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    onClicked(this)
                }
                hasConsumed = true
            }
        }
        hasConsumed
    }
}
```

In the example above we see extension function. I know what it is and can use use/create similar ones. But there's `onClicked: (view: TextView) -> Unit` in the example's parameters. What is this? Callback? I see this kind of parameters too often, but don't have any idea how to understand that. Does it reference to some lambda function? Can someone send me detailed manual/example of this kind of parameters/functions/whatever?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types

Comment: @Michael it's good only as an overview. But I still have no idea how to use them properly.

Comment: Well, you asked for the manual: that's the manual. If there's something you find unclear after reading that, then you should point out what you found unclear specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onClicked` is a function that gets passed to `onEndDrawableClicked`. It's type is a [functional type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) `(view: TextView) -> Unit`. That function, when called, expects one parameter `view` of type `TextView` and returns `Unit`.

So yes, it is a callback, passed as a lambda. It can be used like:

```kotlin
val textView: TextView = ...
textView.onEndDrawableClicked {
  // code that should be executed when onClicked gets called.
}
```

Functions are first class citiziens in Kotlin. Meaning you can store function in variables and pass them to other functions. Or let functions return functions.

**When to use?**

You can pass a function whenever you want to pass behavior (rather than state) to or from your functions. So the caller can decide what to do in those cases. That allows you to write highly flexible code / API's.

Alternatively you could create an interface with one ore many functions to be called and pass an instance of that interface to your function.

Comment: Oh, that's really good explanation. Now I think I should find another example without extension function and try to use information that you wrote. Thank you very much. Good luck :)